# WindowServer crash on MBP 2021

Tags: mac, crash

After logging into my bank account, my MBP turned black for a brief second, then showed me the login screen. All apps had to restart.

Usually I wouldn't mind this, but as it happened the moment I started up my bank account I am wondering if there was any connection.

---

### Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Process:               WindowServer [357]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               88

Date/Time:             2022-06-14 11:55:15.8460 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        0E2F3FAA-4D13-66E5-0F95-85A45B108335

Sleep/Wake UUID:       8135F693-AC27-467F-A867-EA45B303F53E

Time Awake Since Boot: 37000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       173 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fc1c1cc __exceptionPreprocess + 240
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019f96d7b8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fcec488 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fb3a5a0 -[NSTaggedPointerString hash] + 0
4   IOKit                               0x00000001a25c84ac __IOHIDEventDataAppendEventData + 168
5   SkyLight                            0x00000001a4dc1198 _ZL24_SLEventRecordCreateDataPK14SLSEventRecord24SLEventCreateDataOptionsj + 1116
6   SkyLight                            0x00000001a4dc2390 CGSEncodeEventRecord + 76
7   SkyLight                            0x00000001a4e652e4 _ZL17add_events_to_tapP11CGXEventTapP14SLSEventRecordi + 1468
8   SkyLight                            0x00000001a4e64fe4 _ZL17add_events_to_tapP11CGXEventTapP14SLSEventRecordi + 700
9   SkyLight                            0x00000001a4e64fe4 _ZL17add_events_to_tapP11CGXEventTapP14SLSEventRecordi + 700
10  SkyLight                            0x00000001a4e64fe4 _ZL17add_events_to_tapP11CGXEventTapP14SLSEventRecordi + 700
11  SkyLight                            0x00000001a4f5dc44 CGXRunOneEventPass + 1160
12  SkyLight                            0x00000001a4f5e54c _ZL24eventNotificationHandlerjP17mach_msg_header_tPv + 16
13  SkyLight                            0x00000001a4f8be70 post_port_data + 272
14  SkyLight                            0x00000001a4f8bad4 CGXRunOneServicesPass + 1612
15  SkyLight                            0x00000001a4f8c8f0 server_loop + 128
16  SkyLight                            0x00000001a4f8c5b4 SLXServer + 1744
17  WindowServer                        0x000000010458f3bc WindowServer + 13244
18  dyld                                0x00000001047bd0f4 start + 520

Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa9d9b8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad0eb0 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x19fa0e314 abort + 164
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x19fa8db50 abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x19fa7ef64 demangling_terminate_handler() + 332
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19f976140 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x19fa8cee4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x19fa8fc5c __cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 36
8   libc++abi.dylib                        0x19fa8fc08 __cxa_throw + 140
9   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19f96d8dc objc_exception_throw + 352
10  CoreFoundation                         0x19fcec488 _CFThrowFormattedException + 116
11  CoreFoundation                         0x19fb3a5a0 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 220
12  IOKit                                  0x1a25c84ac __IOHIDEventDataAppendEventData + 168
13  SkyLight                               0x1a4dc1198 _SLEventRecordCreateData(SLSEventRecord const*, SLEventCreateDataOptions, unsigned int) + 1116
14  SkyLight                               0x1a4dc2390 CGSEncodeEventRecord + 76
15  SkyLight                               0x1a4e652e4 add_events_to_tap(CGXEventTap*, SLSEventRecord*, int) + 1468
16  SkyLight                               0x1a4e64fe4 add_events_to_tap(CGXEventTap*, SLSEventRecord*, int) + 700
17  SkyLight                               0x1a4e64fe4 add_events_to_tap(CGXEventTap*, SLSEventRecord*, int) + 700
18  SkyLight                               0x1a4e64fe4 add_events_to_tap(CGXEventTap*, SLSEventRecord*, int) + 700
19  SkyLight                               0x1a4f5dc44 CGXRunOneEventPass + 1160
20  SkyLight                               0x1a4f5e54c eventNotificationHandler(unsigned int, mach_msg_header_t*, void*) + 16
21  SkyLight                               0x1a4f8be70 post_port_data + 272
22  SkyLight                               0x1a4f8bad4 CGXRunOneServicesPass + 1612
23  SkyLight                               0x1a4f8c8f0 server_loop + 128
24  SkyLight                               0x1a4f8c5b4 SLXServer + 1744
25  WindowServer                           0x10458f3bc 0x10458c000 + 13244
26  dyld                                   0x1047bd0f4 start + 520

Thread 1:: com.apple.coreanimation.display.primary
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c10274 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::thread_body(void*) + 404
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:: com.apple.coreanimation.frameinfo.primary
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c104bc CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::frame_info_thread_body(void*) + 404
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: com.apple.coreanimation.cursor.primary
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c11b48 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::cursor_thread_body(void*) + 412
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:: com.apple.coreanimation.display.external-0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c10274 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::thread_body(void*) + 404
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:: com.apple.coreanimation.frameinfo.external-0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c104bc CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::frame_info_thread_body(void*) + 404
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:: com.apple.coreanimation.cursor.external-0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c11b48 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::cursor_thread_body(void*) + 412
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:: com.apple.coreanimation.display.dfr
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c10274 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::thread_body(void*) + 404
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 8:: com.apple.coreanimation.frameinfo.dfr
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6c104bc CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::frame_info_thread_body(void*) + 404
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 9:: com.apple.coreanimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a251a8 CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 508
3   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 10:: IOHIDService - RunLoopCompatibilityThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   IOKit                                  0x1a25d598c __IOHIDServiceRunLoopCompatibilityThread + 280
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 11::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.VirtualDisplayListener
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa9ffb4 mach_msg_server_once + 280
3   CoreDisplay                            0x1a0f103b4 -[VirtualDisplayListener rx] + 124
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f910e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f912bac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f91a330 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f91aea4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f925708 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facd304 _pthread_wqthread + 288
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc018 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 12:: com.apple.coreanimation.msr_runloop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95954 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa95d00 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9ced8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9b390 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19fb9a734 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19fc26cc8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   QuartzCore                             0x1a6b4ba48 CA::WindowServer::accelerator_runloop()::'block-literal'::$_0::__invoke(void*) + 208
7   QuartzCore                             0x1a6a24f9c thread_fun(void*) + 32
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 13:: IOHIDEvent Server Connection - Root
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa959a8 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9131b8 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 64
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9137bc _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9240f0 _dispatch_worker_thread + 312
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 14:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa959a8 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9131b8 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 64
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9137bc _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9240f0 _dispatch_worker_thread + 312
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc010 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa959a8 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9131b8 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 64
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9137bc _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9240f0 _dispatch_worker_thread + 312
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc010 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa959a8 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9131b8 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 64
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9137bc _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9240f0 _dispatch_worker_thread + 312
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc010 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc010 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 21:: com.apple.windowserver.root_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19fa959a8 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9131b8 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 64
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9137bc _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19f9240f0 _dispatch_worker_thread + 312
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19fad1240 _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19facc024 thread_start + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
x4: 0x000000019fa910ad   x5: 0x000000016b8617d0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000600
x8: 0xaef1b9b2d3aebbba   x9: 0xaee439b3d72dbe3a  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x000000000000000b
x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000002
x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001fa307530  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
x20: 0x0000000104830580  x21: 0x0000000000000103  x22: 0x0000000121a1afc0  x23: 0x000000028d92e830
x24: 0x0000000000000002  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000000000000f0
x28: 0x00000001f14da170   fp: 0x000000016b861740   lr: 0x000000019fad0eb0
sp: 0x000000016b861720   pc: 0x000000019fa9d9b8 cpsr: 0x40001000
far: 0x000000019fa8b970  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x19fa94000 -        0x19fac9fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <384945e6-dd71-37e5-9a3d-84fff14a1e60> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x19faca000 -        0x19fad6fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x19f995000 -        0x19fa15fff libsystem_c.dylib (*) <0dbc8b95-0037-3725-a769-0c772c293488> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x19fa7a000 -        0x19fa93fff libc++abi.dylib (*) <8f8963c1-403d-3282-ae5e-4f6e0e85f5a6> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x19f956000 -        0x19f991fff libobjc.A.dylib (*) <2eb32e1d-90cb-3256-8681-9034085a06a6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x19fb18000 -        0x1a005bfff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <35473de6-c433-332c-aee0-013fd5f6d4fd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x1a2579000 -        0x1a264efff com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2) <97e3d808-8bcb-3ac4-85ab-60faa4cae04f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1a4c9d000 -        0x1a5069fff com.apple.SkyLight (1.600.0)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight
0x10458c000 -        0x10458ffff WindowServer (*) <03f47bf0-ec03-322b-b7dc-514dc1476743> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
0x1047b8000 -        0x104817fff dyld (*)  /usr/lib/dyld
0x1a69de000 -        0x1a6cdcfff com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11) <0c98ecde-c21a-3501-9c98-fc9d3dd5bb12> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x1a0efe000 -        0x1a101dfff com.apple.CoreDisplay (264) <3e527172-a277-3b69-91ae-6b69ff38c0e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
0x19f90f000 -        0x19f955fff libdispatch.dylib (*) <93e1dcfc-ef56-3113-8e7c-1ba85266a93b> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib

External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=794.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=794.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.9G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.9G(100%)

```
                            VIRTUAL   REGION
```

REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
===========                     =======  =======
Activity Tracing                   256K        1
CG backing stores                 36.5M      204
CG raster data                    25.9M       47
ColorSync                          640K       29
CoreAnimation                    603.0M     1710
CoreGraphics                       208K       13
Dispatch continuations            64.0M        1
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1
MALLOC                           268.3M      149
MALLOC guard page                  192K       10
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         944.0M        8         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Mach message (reserved)             32K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.3M       22
Stack                             21.1M       22
VM_ALLOCATE                      106.1M     3819
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)             240K       15         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__AUTH                            1849K      156
__AUTH_CONST                      9308K      301
__CGSERVER                          16K        1
__DATA                            8734K      299
__DATA_CONST                       9.9M      320
__DATA_DIRTY                       713K      113
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1
__LINKEDIT                       576.8M       22
__OBJC_CONST                      1175K      123
__OBJC_RO                         82.1M        1
__OBJC_RW                         3104K        1
__SLSERVER                          16K        1
__TEXT                           217.6M      332
__UNICODE                          588K        1
dyld private memory               1024K        1
mapped file                       48.0M       11
shared memory                     1536K       50
===========                     =======  =======
TOTAL                              3.0G     7787
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.1G     7787

---

### Full Report

{"app_name":"WindowServer","timestamp":"2022-06-14 11:55:20.00 +0100","app_version":"","slice_uuid":"03f47bf0-ec03-322b-b7dc-514dc1476743","build_version":"","platform":1,"share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":1,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.2.1 (21D62)","incident_id":"A9C270D7-E7CF-4693-9448-7E8113F14750","name":"WindowServer"}
{
"uptime" : 37000,
"procLaunch" : "2022-06-13 11:42:41.8917 +0100",
"procRole" : "Graphics",
"version" : 2,
"userID" : 88,
"deployVersion" : 210,
"modelCode" : "MacBookPro17,1",
"procStartAbsTime" : 603746389,
"coalitionID" : 316,
"osVersion" : {
"train" : "macOS 12.2.1",
"build" : "21D62",
"releaseType" : "User"
},
"captureTime" : "2022-06-14 11:55:15.8460 +0100",
"incident" : "A9C270D7-E7CF-4693-9448-7E8113F14750",
"bug_type" : "309",
"pid" : 357,
"procExitAbsTime" : 903808933147,
"translated" : false,
"cpuType" : "ARM-64",
"procName" : "WindowServer",
"procPath" : "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer",
"parentProc" : "launchd",
"parentPid" : 1,
"coalitionName" : "com.apple.WindowServer",
"crashReporterKey" : "0E2F3FAA-4D13-66E5-0F95-85A45B108335",
"wakeTime" : 173,
"sleepWakeUUID" : "8135F693-AC27-467F-A867-EA45B303F53E",
"sip" : "enabled",
"isCorpse" : 1,
"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
"ktriageinfo" : "VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get\nVM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get\nVM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get\nVM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get\nVM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get\n",
"asi" : {"CoreFoundation":["*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'"],"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"],"libc++abi.dylib":["terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"]},
"asiBacktraces" : ["0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fc1c1cc __exceptionPreprocess + 240\n1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019f96d7b8 objc_exception_throw + 60\n2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fcec488 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0\n3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019fb3a5a0 -[NSTaggedPointerString hash] + 0\n4   IOKit                               0x00000001a25c84ac __IOHIDEventDataAppendEventData + 168\n5   SkyLight                            0x00000001a4dc1198 _ZL24_SLEventRecordCreateDataPK14SLSEventRecord24SLEventCreateDataOptionsj + 1116\n6

Comment: I assume you were using a web browser to access your bank account. After the restart, were you able to login successfully, or did the problem recur?

Comment: The same error didn't happen again, but my activity monitor shows that there is something going on with that bank (N26). 
It says that my computer has run all night and day, 13 hours/13 hours possible.
1h20m out of that just for app.n26.com